# What is meant by the 'context' of an operation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, socket.io

I am trying to combine socket.io with backbone.js.

I have found a piece of starting code online, which I understand 99%. The only problem I have is understanding the following line:

> In the code below the only item added to the default model or collection is this.ctx, which is optional. It is used to provide a
>   **context** for the operation and should be defined upon initializing a
>   Backbone model or collection.

What is ment by contect. Is it used to pass variables ?? Is it used to pass a callback ??

The complete code can de found here: [Backbone.js and socket.io](http://developer.teradata.com/blog/jasonstrimpel/2011/11/backbone-js-and-socket-io)

I have tried to figure this out for myself for quite some time now, and I can make the code work whilst working my way around it. But I am curious what the writer actually intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally in JS a context refers to the object that `this` refers to within a function like an event handler. For instance, assume the below made-up event registration function accepts a callback as its third argument and a context as its fourth argument, and you call it like this:

```
var contextObject = { 'testProperty' : 'test' };

registerEvent(someElement, 'click', function() {
    var a = this.testProperty; // 'a' is 'test'
}, contextObject);
```